# Unknown error on PySpark map + broadcast

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a big group of tuples with `tuple[0] = integer` and `tuple[1] = list of integers` (resulting from a `groupBy`). I call the value `tuple[0]` key for simplicity.

The values inside the lists `tuple[1]` can be eventually other keys.

If `key = n`, all elements of key are greater than n and sorted / distinct.

In the problem I am working on, I need to find the number of common elements in the following way:

`0, [1,2]`

`1, [3,4,5]`

`2, [3,7,8]`

`.....`

list of values of key `0`:

`1: [3,4,5]`

`2: [3,7,8]`

common_elements between list of `1` and list of `2`:  `3` -> `len(common_elements) = 1`

Then I apply the same for keys `1, 2 etc`, so:

list of values of `1`:

`3: ....`

`4: ....`

`5: ....`

The sequential script I wrote is based on pandas DataFrame `df`, with the first column `v` as list of 'keys' (`as index = True`) and the second column `n` as list of list of values:

```
for i in df.v: #iterate each value 
    for j in df.n[i]: #iterate within the list
        common_values = set(df.n[i]).intersection(df.n[j])
        if len(common_values) > 0:
             return len(common_values)
```

Since is a big dataset, I'm trying to write a parallelized version with PySpark.

```
df.A #column of integers 
df.B #column of integers 

val_colA = sc.parallelize(df.A)
val_colB = sc.parallelize(df.B)
n_values = val_colA.zip(val_colB).groupByKey().MapValues(sorted) # RDD -> n_values[0] will be the key, n_values[1] is the list of values 
n_values_broadcast = sc.broadcast(n_values.collectAsMap()) #read only dictionary

def f(element):
    for i in element[1]: #iterating the values of "key" element[0] 
        common_values =  set(element[1]).intersection(n_values_broadcast.value[i]) 
        if len(common_values) > 0:
             return len(common_values)

collection = n_values.map(f).collect()
```

The programs fails after few seconds giving error like `KeyError: 665` but does not provide any specific failure reason.

I'm a  Spark beginner thus not sure whether this the correct approach (should I consider `foreach` instead? or `mapPartition`) and especially where is the error.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is actually pretty clear and Spark specific. You are accessing Python `dict` with `__getitem__` (`[]`):

```
n_values_broadcast.value[i]
```

and if key is missing in the dictionary you'll get `KeyError`. Use `get` method instead:

```
n_values_broadcast.value.get(i, [])
```